# Can't compile contract - pragma error and Cannot read property 'interface' of undefined

Tags: blockchain, solc, abi, compiler

I am trying to compile this simple contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract Tasks
{

    struct TaskOwner {
      address TaskOwnerAddress;
      bytes32 TaskOwnerName;
    }
    mapping (address => TaskOwner) public theTaskOwner;

    //Task owner information
    address TaskOwnerAddress;
    bytes32 TaskOwnerName;

    modifier onlyOwner(){
      if(msg.sender != TaskOwnerAddress) revert();
      _;
    }

    event NewTaskStarted(bytes32 TaskOwnerName, address TaskOwnerAddress);


    function Tasks(bytes32 TaskOwnerName) {

        //establish the owner
        TaskOwnerAddress = msg.sender;
        TaskOwnerName    = TaskOwnerName;

        //fire a new Task started event
        NewTaskStarted(TaskOwnerName, TaskOwnerAddress);
    }
}
```

using this script in the contracts directory after starting rpc in another Mac terminal tab:

```
node

Web3 = require('web3')
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

code = fs.readFileSync('Tasks.sol').toString()
solc = require('solc')
compileCode = solc.compile(code)

abiDefinition = JSON.parse(compileCode.contracts[':Tasks'].interface)
```

but the solc.compile produces this warning:

> compileCode = solc.compile(code)
>   { contracts: {},
>     errors: [ ':1:1: Warning: Source file does not specify required compiler version!Consider adding "pragma solidity ^0.4.18\n\n^\n' ],
>     sourceList: [ '' ],
>     sources: { '': { AST: [Object] } } }

and then when I use this command next:

```
abiDefinition = JSON.parse(compileCode.contracts[':Tasks'].interface)
```

produces this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'interface' of undefined
    at repl:1:59
    at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:22:35)
    at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:73:12)
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:21:12)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:340:29)
    at bound (domain.js:280:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:293:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:538:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:233:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:584:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:861:14)
    at REPLServer.self._ttyWrite (repl.js:611:7)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:120:10)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at emitKeys (internal/readline.js:389:14)
    at next (native)
    at ReadStream.onData (readline.js:971:36)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at ReadStream.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
    at TTY.onread (net.js:547:20)
```

I'm trying to understand why it is saying that there is no pragma comment when there is. And I'm trying to understand the meaning of the TypeError: Cannot read property as well.

I am running this in the contracts directory of this truffle unbox pet-shop file structure.

Any comments to improve the code would be appreciated as well as I am learning solidity.

Thank you

Comment: Because compile filed, `compileCode.contracts[':Tasks']` is undefined.  So that explains the second error.

As for the first, main error, seems like it's not reading your file properly.  Have you tried to console.log `code`? And obviously `Tasks.sol` in the same folder as the script?
I just tried this, and it worked for me.

Comment: Hi carlolm, where would i place console.log code ? and is that the exact syntax? I usually see something like console.log(somecommand). Also, I'm not running the script in the file but pasting it in at the web3.js prompt (>). It's good to know that it is worked for you, I agree that it doesn't seem to be reading my file correctly.

Comment: (just noticed, previous message: compile "failed").
You can run `console.log(code)` after the `code =  ...` line.
Just to check if it's reading the file

Comment: I tried compiling it in remix and it did not report the pragma error but I did get this: Tasks errored: Error encoding arguments: SyntaxError: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 1

Comment: OK carlolm - you are on to something. I get an empty string for code when I do this even though I'm in the directory with the contract file (Tasks.sol)    : > code = fs.readFileSync('Tasks.sol').toString()
'' (my note this is an empty string so it's not finding the string)
> 
(To exit, press ^C again or type .exit)
> 
MacBook-Pro:contracts user1$ ls
Migrations.sol Tasks.sol .

Comment: In remix, are you passing in an argument into the constructor when you hit create?
Make sure you use double quotes: "task owner name"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67462/discussion-between-jazzmine-and-carlolm).

Comment: All: My problem was I was pointing to an empty file rather than another copy of the file in a different directory. Thanks carlolm.

Comment: For future reference - I also got this error a second time, which the contract name didn't match the filename. I had done a global change and inadvertently changed the contract name. So if you happen to get this error, also check to make sure your contract name matched your filename.

Answer (score -1):

The class name must be the file name. Try with that and everything will work.